# Uniformity of sequential convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a compact metric space $(K,d)$ and a continuous function $f : K \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that for any point $x \in K$, I have a sequence $(x_n) \subset K$ such that $d(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Clearly, by sequential continuity of $f$, I also have $|f(x_n)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. In other words, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \geq N(x)$, $|f(x_n)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$.

I am wondering if I can make the convergence uniform on $x \in K$ by compactness ? That is, is it true that for any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $\sup_{x \in K} |f(x_n)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ ?

I suppose that my question is closely linked to the fact that $f$ is in fact uniformly continuous but I was not able to write a proper argument.

Could you provide me with some hints?

Comment: On *any* metric space $K$, given *any* $x\in K$, there is some sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $K$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x)=0$; simply take $x_n=x$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. So, your assumption always holds.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the answer! I probably have asked the question poorly but what I mean is that for any $x \in K$, I have a given sequence such that $d(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$ and I am wondering if it implies $\sup_{x \in K} |f(x_n)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the statement is this:

> Let $K$ be a compact metric space, let, for each $x\in K$, $(a_{x,n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a sequence of elements of $K$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{x,n}=x$, and let $f\colon K\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Then is it true that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\sup_{x\in K}\bigl|f(a_{x,n})-f(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon?$$

The answer is negative. Take $K=[0,1]$ (with its usual metric) and $f(x)=x$. For each $x\in[0,1]$, define$$a_{x,n}=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=\frac1m\text{ for some }m\in\Bbb N\text{ with }n\leqslant m\\x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$For instance, the sequence $(a_{1/3,n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is the sequence $1,1,1,\frac13,\frac13,\frac13,\frac13,\ldots$ Then, if you take, $\varepsilon=\frac12$, you will have, for any $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$, $\sup_{x\in K}\bigl|f(a_{x,n})-f(x)\bigr|\geqslant\frac12=\varepsilon$. That's so because$$\left|f\left(a_{1/n,n}\right)-f\left(\frac1n\right)\right|=\left|1-\frac1n\right|=1-\frac1n\geqslant\frac12.$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.